# Remove text label in Kendo radar charts

Tags: charts, kendo-ui, frontend, kendo-chart, radar-chart

I'm trying to remove a label text in my Kendo radar chart, illustrated by the red box on the image below.

[image: Radar chart]

Does anyone know how to remove these informations from my chart?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To add some information about the question, here is the documentation URL:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/series-types/radar/


,and stackblitz link to the source:

https://stackblitz.com/run/?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the labels by setting the visible property of labels to false. Please find below the code where you need to add the property.

```
<kendo-chart-value-axis>
  <kendo-chart-value-axis-item [labels]="{ visible:false, format: 'C0' }">
  </kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
</kendo-chart-value-axis>
```